# Printing out the value pointed by pointer (C Programming)

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I would like to print out the contents a pointer pointing to. Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    int* pt = NULL;
    *pt = 100;
    printf("%d\n",*pt);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me a segmentation fault. Why?

Comment: When you point to something it has to exist. Try `malloc` and then it will exist!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These lines:

```
int* pt = NULL;
*pt = 100;
```

are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (i.e. you try to store value `100` into the memory at address `NULL`), which results in ***undefined behavor***. Try:

```
int i = 0;
int *p = &i;
*p = 100;
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are trying to write to address NULL.

Try:

```
int main(){
    int val = 0;
    int* pt = &val;
    *pt = 100;
    printf("%d\n",*pt);
    return 0;
}
```